# Reuse the same mongo db query result for the continuous two requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a scenario like, there are two requests from client continuously

> get('/allUsers')
>
> get('/structuredData')

these two request will, in turn, calls the same mongoose query which will return a bulk data as a result. But I have to process the data differently in each request.

Here, I want to reuse the result of the mongoose query by executing it only once as more time is wasted in executing the same query twice.

Need a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

If the data stored in mongodb will be changed frequently, I'd recommend you to just query.

If the data won't be changed frequently, you can cache the data to a global variable or redis.

By variables:

```
var users, lastTimestamp;

function getAllUser(req, res, next) {

}

function getStructuredData(req, res, next) {

}

function getData(req, res, next) {
  if(!users || Date.now() - lastTimestamp > 1000 * 60) {
    query('some query', function(err, data) {
      if(err)
        return next(err);
      users = data;
      lastTimestamp = Date.now();
      next();
    });
  }
}

app.get('/allUsers', getData, getAllUser);

app.get('/structuredData', getData, getStructuredData);
```

Comment: No, the data won't change frequently. I tried caching the data to redis. But writing the data to the redis cache is taking more time, by that time if I execute the same query again, I would get the result.

Comment: Thank you this rings a bell to me :)